# jQuery wait for dynamic images to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page that is dynamically loading images at user request, basically a random image will pop up when they click a button. I want to find a way to hide the image until it finishes loading and then have it show again. I've tried doing this with jQuery's $(window).load() function and it works perfectly for the first image but when I load the next image the event doesn't fire again. Is there another way to do this, or to reset the load() event? Thanks.

Note: The images in question are rather large animated gifs but they very, some only take a few moments to load and some can take up to 20 seconds.

Comment: It is possible to do, but you need to show us the code you're using so we can advise.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [jQuery plugin called *waitForImages*](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) that will help with that.

```
$('#newly-loaded-element').hide().waitForImages(function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: Would this plugin work if the image src attribute was changed afterwards to load a new image using the same <img> tag?

Comment: @guub No, you would need to call it again after updating the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Hide it using CSS and listen to each image's load event:

```
<img style="display: none" class="loadedImage" src="..." />

$(function(){
    $(".loadedImage").live("load", function(){
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's my understanding from the `.live()` documentation that `.live()` doesn't work for load events.  It only works for certain types of events that bubble to the document.  See the "caveats" section here: http://api.jquery.com/live/.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I originally wanted to write the simple ".load()" but since I wasn't so sure of what _dynamically loaded images_ meant (whether the markup is there already and only the src is changing or what), I inserted the `.live()`

Answer (score -1):

its called Lazy-Load and there is a specific [JQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazykarl) for it.